# starling viewport in a flex mxml application

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, starling-framework

I'm trying to create a flex mxml project that contains a starling viewport.

If I create an actionscript project, that I extend Sprite and am able to work with starling.

but if my main project is an MXML File, I can't seem to add the starling viewport to the stage.

so in general what I need is a simple hello world example that uses starling using an mxml main page.

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

try s:SpriteVisualElement
and add some starling sprite to it.

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/11/20/adding-a-sprite-to-the-display-list-in-flex-4/

hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

see [here][1]  http://www.hsharma.com/tutorials/starting-with-starling-ep-1-intro-setup/
  [1]

and here http://www.hsharma.com/tutorials/

saludos